# FFMPEG: Create contiguous videos from webcam

Tags: html, video, ffmpeg, webcam, media-source

Can FFMPEG record from webcam in (for instance 10 sec.) intervals ?
I need contiguous small videos from webcam (used for a p2p live streaming app, which I'm developing), so that I can play them one after the after without noticing, that there are actually multiple videos.

I guess, I have to break on key-frames or something like this, so that I have clear cuts.

For playing multiple videos without stuttering I use the Web MediaSource API and it does actually work quite well already.

I only need to segment a webcam stream into multiple variable video files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the general purpose [stream segmenter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) or the specific [Apple HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) segmenter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1).

Example for the stream segmenter on Linux:

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -an -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart out%03d.mp4`

You can set a constant keyframe interval with the GOP size option (`-g`), ie:

`-c:v libx264 -r 25 -g 50`

puts a keyframe every 2s (50 frames at 25 fps). The segment duration must be a multiple of the keyframe interval.